# T-SQL: number of attribute changes by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I'm looking for a way to count the number of changes of an attribute of a particular group such as customer.

**Data**

```
Customer  |  Attribute
A         |  x
A         |  x
A         |  y
A         |  x
A         |  y
B         |  x
B         |  y
B         |  x
C         |  x
```

**Result**

```
Customer  |  Attribute
A         |  3
B         |  2
C         |  0
```

I've tried to work with *DISTINCT*, however this does not catch the case of customer A, where the value changes back to its initial value.

Thanks and best regard

Comment: Number of changes? According to what?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ou need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, let me assume that you have another column that specifies the ordering, which I'll represent with a `?`.

Then you can use `lag()` (or `lead()`):

```
select customer,
       sum(case when prev_attribute <> attribute then 1 else 0 end) as num_changes
from (select t.*, lag(attribute) over (partition by customer order by ?) as prev_attribute
      from t
     ) t
group by customer;
```